# Git: Splitting a file out into a new repository

Tags: windows, git, file, export, history

Splitting a subfolder out into a new repository:

```
git subtree split --prefix=Folder1 --branch second_export
git remote add newserver http://github.com/repo.git
git push newserver second_export
```

When splitting a folder into a separate repository, you won't lose any of your Git history or changes.

**Q: how to split a single file?**